# Using Multiple Files in C++ for functions and classes

Tags: c++, function, class, file-io, include

I am trying to figure out how to make a program consisting of separate files.  I read this post:

[Function Implementation in Separate File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378219/function-implementation-in-separate-file)

But have not succeeded.  I have 3 files:  main.cpp, func.cpp, time.h and when I compile, I get this error message:

```
duplicate symbol getOpen(std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)in:
    /var/folders/kp/57zkm0tn1q7b7w0cs7tlf98c0000gn/T//cczaW1Px.o
    /var/folders/kp/57zkm0tn1q7b7w0cs7tlf98c0000gn/T//ccvOCRgc.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have no idea what this means.  I'm basically just trying to open a file, write to it, and close it.  I also just created an object and tested it.  I know the problem is from func.cpp because when I remove that it works.  Can someone please advise?  Thank you.

I type this to compile:  `g++ main.cpp func.cpp`.

This is my code:

### time.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

class Time
{
    private:
        int seconds;
        int minutes;
        int hours;
    public:
        Time(int=0, int=0, int=0);
        Time(long);
        void showTime();
};

Time::Time(int sec, int min, int hour)
{
    seconds = sec;
    minutes = min;
    hours = hour;
}

Time::Time(long sec)
{
    hours = int(sec / 3600);
    minutes = int((sec % 3600)/60);
    seconds = int( (sec%60) );
}

void Time::showTime()
{
    cout << setfill('0')
         << setw(2) << hours << ':'
         << setw(2) << minutes << ':'
         << setw(2) << seconds << endl;
}
```

### func.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int getOpen(ofstream& fileOut)
{
    string filename = "outfile.txt";
    fileOut.open(filename.c_str());

    if( fileOut.fail())
    {
        cout << "\nFailed to open file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"
#include "func.cpp"

int main()
{
    ofstream outFile;
    Time t1;

    t1.showTime();

    getOpen(outFile);

    outFile << "This is a test" << endl;

    outFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also, is typical to include all function prototypes in a header file?

Comment: Yes, it is. In your case, it could be 'func.h'. And consider using #ifdef guards in the header files (to prevent including their contents twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You included `"func.cpp"` into `main.cpp`, so you have a double declaration of `getOpen`.

Comment: It's the standard thing to do, indeed - prototypes in .h file, definitions in .cpp file (and include the header in the .cpp).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't `#include "func.cpp"` into `main.cpp`.

Well, it depends on how you compile your program. If you compile only main.cpp, then you should include func.cpp. But that's not a nice way to write a program, and I hope you are not going to do that.

What you might want to do is to compile main.cpp and func.cpp separately (using `gcc -c`) and then link the `.o` files. That would be perfectly ok if you don't include one .cpp file into another. But when you include func.cpp into main.cpp, both of the `.o` files define `getOpen` function. That causes the error.

So: just remove the #include in main.

Comment: Thanks so much!  could you give me the commands you would type to compile and link?  I was just doing `g++ main.cpp func.cpp`?